# How to retrieve, delete, and emit assets in a webpack 5 plugin?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I've been working on migrating my webpack plugin over to webpack 5, but have been running into some issues:

**The original (Webpack 4) plugin:**

```
apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.emit.tap("DtsBundlerPlugin", (compilation) => {
        // Get assets whose name ends in ".d.ts", 
        // bundle them, emit single ".d.ts" file.
    });
}
```

**The Warning:**

```
BREAKING CHANGE: No more changes should happen to Compilation.assets after sealing the Compilation.
        Do changes to assets earlier, e. g. in Compilation.hooks.processAssets.
        Make sure to select an appropriate stage from Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_*.
```

**The Problem:**

So I get it, I can't modify assets this late in the compilation and it has to be done earlier. So I did that:

```
apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap("DtsBundlerPlugin", (compilation) => {
        compilation.hooks.processAssets.tap({
            name: "DtsBundlerPlugin",
            state: Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_OPTIMIZE_INLINE,
        }, (assets) => {
            // Get assets whose name ends in ".d.ts", 
            // bundle them, emit single ".d.ts" file.
        })
    });
}
```

But the ".d.ts" assets (being generated by `ts-loader`) don't appear at the:

- `processAssets` phase
- `afterProcessAssets` phase

They don't show up until `needAdditionalSeal` which is too late to modify assets. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Is this some kind of bug? Am I missing a phase?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [ts-loader/after-compile.ts](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/64a41369e0fc49638935dbc88c975f75c1e825fc/src/after-compile.ts#L392) I found a comment saying

> In webpack 5 only errors should be provided during aftercompile.  Assets should be emitted during the afterProcessAssets hook

Trying this, I got something similar to what you want to do to work with

```js
compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('DeclarationPlugin', (compilation) => {
      //NOTE: even though the stage comes from the processAssets hook and not the afterProcessAssets hook
      // strangely this only works for me WITH the stage defined
      compilation.hooks.afterProcessAssets.tap({
        stage: Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_OPTIMIZE,
        name:'DeclarationPlugin'
      },() => {
        compilation.getAssets().forEach((asset,key) => {
          //...do things and then delete original declaration files
          compilation.deleteAsset(asset.name);
        });
        //... add combined declaration files 
        compilation.emitAsset(
          'path/to/combined-declarations.d.ts',
           new webpack.sources.RawSource(combinedDeclaration)
        );
      }});
});
```